# Optional Boolean Query Parameter Not Showing Up In Swagger

Tags: swagger, nestjs, class-transformer, nestjs-swagger

I'm using Nest.js with Swagger and the [Swagger CLI](https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin) enabled. I have an endpoint in a controller which has an optional boolean query parameter: `includeAll` that defaults to false. The endpoint looks like:

```
  @Get()
  findAll(
    @Query('includeArtifacts', ParseOptionalBool)
    includeArtifacts = false,
  ) {
    return this.toursService.findAll({ includeArtifacts });
  }
```

I'm using an Injectable Pipe Transform similar to [what is described](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#transformation-use-case) in the docs to parse the **optional** boolean value seen here:

```
export const toBoolean = (value?: string): boolean => {
  value = value?.toLowerCase();

  return value === 'true' || value === '1';
};

@Injectable()
export class ParseOptionalBool implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value?: any, metadata?: ArgumentMetadata): any {
    return toBoolean(value);
  }
}
```

Everything functions successfully; however, as seen below when I view the endpoint in Swagger there is no mention of my `includeArtifacts` endpoint.

[image: Image of swagger docs with no parameter data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create simple class like this below:

```
export class ParseOptionalBool {
  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @IsBooleanString()
  @IsOptional()
  includeArtifacts: boolean;
}
```

and your controller will be like this:

```
 @Get()
  findAll(
    @Query() dto: ParseOptionalBool;
  ) {
    return this.toursService.findAll(dto);
  }
```

but this will return object with string type, not boolean type, if you want to parse boolean type, you should do like this below:

```
  @ApiPropertyOptional()
  @IsBoolean()
  @IsOptional()
  @Transform(({ obj }) => obj.includeArtifacts == 'true')
  includeArtifacts: boolean;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try this tonight and if it works send the bounty.